# Unable to change datasource in Crystal Reports 2010

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have a Crystal Report being called from a vb.net app and I'm trying to change the datasource from SQL Server to MySQL. I have modified the ODBC data source and it tests ok. However, when I try to change the datasource in Crystal using (Database, Set Datasource Location) it fails with the message "some tables could not be replaced, as no match was found in the new data source". The message occurs after I've setup the new connection and then selected the existing datasource and the new one then press the update button.

I've tried doing each table separately, after clicking the Update button it doesn't do anything (no message, nothing).

Any help?

Vic

Comment: The error message would seem to indicate that one or more of the tables that the report is looking for either do not exist in the new database **or** cannot be found if they do exist. When you set the data source location can see the tables that the report is looking for?

Comment: Yes it does seem to indicate that but there are only 3 tables in the report and all 3 exist in the new connection database. Also, I can't even update a single table.

Comment: OK - it does seem to be working if I do each table individually. However, I had to five it a new alias because for some reason I was getting a message "invalid characters in each table.  The names were nodes and customer_information which I don't understand why. But it works now.

Comment: correction - I had to rename each table to get it to work ...

Comment: Yes, it's not the easiest or most user friendly thing to do, but I'm glad you've sorted it out. Once you've done it once it becomes easier.